# How far under the sea is sunlight at 50% of surface level?

Tags: visible-light

I am trying to figure out how deep underwater you need to go before it is only half as bright as the surface.

Actually, a chart mapping depth to percentage of surface light would be really nice, but I haven't been able to find one..

Comment: Different wavelengths are absorbed differently. So, one could have 50% of 1. number of photons, 2. energy, 3. human perceived 'brightness', all of which are likely different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are after??

[image]

From [Attentuation of light through seawater](http://oceanography-leahmoore.blogspot.com/2010/10/light-attenuation-for-various-colors-of.html)